# Concord (VS debugger) method chaining question

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

I try to uinderstand how method chaining (calling previous or default implementation) works (https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Component-discovery-and-configuration) but still have many doubts.

- DkmExample seems to be dispatcher, but how this class is defined ? Can I define such class ?
- Concord interfaces (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.ComponentInterfaces) do not pass dispatcher in their methods, so how it can be added in implementation ? Do any Concord interface can be chained this way ?
- can anyone show how to implement method chaining in https://github.com/microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/tree/master/HelloWorld/Cs (show how to call default implementation), or provide other real exapmle ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have another question, related to VS debugging and Concord, hopefully Pierson will be able to answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061363/how-to-implement-idkmcustomvisualizer-for-managed-target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Method Chaining Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Component-discovery-and-configuration#method-chaining) `IDkmExample` represents an interface that is part of the Concord API. This is the interface you, as the developer, are implementing. In the method call itself, `DkmExample` is not the `dispatcher` but rather a `dispatcher object` that the dispatcher knows how to handle. These are defined by the dispatcher and cannot be defined externally.

The method chaining example is there to show that if the implementation does not want to handle the call of the interface method, then it can call the method of the same name on the `dispatcher object` (first item in the API method signature), passing in all the parameters that are taken by the method signature minus the dispatcher object itself. This will allow the dispatcher to pass the call, based on filtering and priority, to the next implementation of the interface that it can find.

For a concrete example,  we can look at the following block from the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Engine.xml` from the `microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.engine` nuget package:

```xml
<member name="M:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.ComponentInterfaces.IDkmStartDebuggingOperations.LaunchDebuggedProcess(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Start.DkmProcessLaunchRequest)">
    <summary>
    Causes the debug monitor to create a new process under the debugger. The process
    should be left suspended until ResumeDebuggedProcess is called. The debug monitor
    must wait for ResumeDebuggedProcess before creating the DkmProcess object since
    it needs the UniqueProcessId value from the AD7 Layer.

    Note that this method may only be called in response to the Visual Studio
    debugger package requesting a launch. Components that wish to launch another
    process under the debugger should send a custom event to a visual studio package.
    From a package, a launch can be requested through the
    IVsDebugger.LaunchDebugTargets API.
    </summary>
    <param name="request">
    [In] DkmProcessLaunchRequest is used to describe the process that debugger should
    launch.
    </param>
    <returns>
    [Out] DkmLaunchedProcessInfo is returned from APIs that launch a process.
    </returns>
</member>
```

The interface we are overriding is `IDkmStartDebuggingOperations` and the method is `LaunchDebuggedProcess` which in the implementation will take a `DkmProcessLaunchRequest`, which is a `dispatcher object`. If the implementation does not want to handle the call, it can call the next implementation by taking the `dispatcher object` and calling the method of the same name on it, passing the necessary parameters.

For example:

```cs
internal class MyStartDebuggingOperations : IDkmStartDebuggingOperations
{
    public DkmLaunchedProcessInfo LaunchDebuggedProcess(DkmProcessLaunchRequest request)
    {
        if (/* custom check that this class is to handle it */)
        {
            // Handle custom implementation here
        }
        else
        {
            // This calls the base implementation
            return request.LaunchDebuggedProcess();
        }
    }
}
```