# How to implement IDkmCustomVisualizer for managed target

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

So far I was able to run and [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Cpp-Custom-Visualizer-Sample) that implement this interface and using it for debug C++ apps.
I try to implement IDkmCustomVisualizer in C#, aiming use it to debug CLR apps. Is this possible ? 
I retrofitted [Hello Wrold sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Hello-World-Sample), where added class that implement IDkmCustomVisualizer and changed HelloWorld.vsdconfigxml. But nothing works, debugger in experimental instance do not use this implementation. Tried with VS 2017 and 2019 Community.

my IDkmCustomVisualizer implementation:

```
public class CSF : IDkmCustomVisualizer
{
    void crf()
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete("c:/uuu.txt");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:/uuu.txt", "ooo");
    }

    void IDkmCustomVisualizer.EvaluateVisualizedExpression(DkmVisualizedExpression visualizedExpression, out DkmEvaluationResult resultObject)
    {
        crf();
        visualizedExpression.EvaluateVisualizedExpression(out resultObject);
    }

    void IDkmCustomVisualizer.UseDefaultEvaluationBehavior(DkmVisualizedExpression visualizedExpression, out bool useDefaultEvaluationBehavior, out DkmEvaluationResult defaultEvaluationResult)
    {
        crf();
        visualizedExpression.UseDefaultEvaluationBehavior(out useDefaultEvaluationBehavior, out defaultEvaluationResult);
    }

    void IDkmCustomVisualizer.GetChildren(DkmVisualizedExpression visualizedExpression, int initialRequestSize, DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, out DkmChildVisualizedExpression[] initialChildren, out DkmEvaluationResultEnumContext enumContext)
    {
        crf();
        visualizedExpression.GetChildren(initialRequestSize, inspectionContext, out initialChildren, out enumContext);
    }

    void IDkmCustomVisualizer.GetItems(DkmVisualizedExpression visualizedExpression, DkmEvaluationResultEnumContext enumContext, int startIndex, int count, out DkmChildVisualizedExpression[] items)
    {
        crf();
        visualizedExpression.GetItems(enumContext, startIndex, count, out items);
    }

    void IDkmCustomVisualizer.SetValueAsString(DkmVisualizedExpression visualizedExpression, string value, int timeout, out string errorText)
    {
        crf();
        visualizedExpression.SetValueAsString(value, timeout, out errorText);
    }

    string IDkmCustomVisualizer.GetUnderlyingString(DkmVisualizedExpression visualizedExpression)
    {
        crf();
        var ret = visualizedExpression.GetUnderlyingString();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

and HelloWorld.vsdconfigxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/vsdconfig/2008">

  <ManagedComponent
    ComponentId="C4256689-AC45-4B10-BFD3-4036CEE1863A"
    ComponentLevel="9992000"
    AssemblyName="HelloWorld">

    <Class Name="HelloWorld.CSF" >

      <Implements>
        <InterfaceGroup>
          <NoFilter></NoFilter>
          <Interface Name="IDkmCustomVisualizer"/>
        </InterfaceGroup>
      </Implements>
    </Class>

  </ManagedComponent>
</Configuration>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect that the Managed Expression Evaluator (EE) does not call a custom Visualizer.

The sample is for `C/C++` Visualization because the C++ expression evaluator allows  you to customize it. The managed expression evaluator doesn't look like it has that capability but you can verify by looking at the dispatcher logs. You can enable logging following this article (https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Getting-troubleshooting-logs) and see if the custom visualizers is getting called at all.

Comment: Is your goal to customize data in the watch window or are you looking custom UI.

Comment: For now I want replace VS provided type viewers with my own viewers. In longer terms I want customize data in the watch window, using attributes. 
IDebugCustomViewer seems to be good for implementing custom viewers, but it is COM. Is there equivalent to this in Concord ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pierson's advice for analyze logs was helpful, and finally I was able to run IDkmCustomVisualizer implemented in C# but only for debugging C++ apps. For managed apps it is not called. 
Found good alternative IDkmLanguageExpressionEvaluator that implemented in C# is called by both managed and unmagaged (C++) apps.

Comment: Hi codefox, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)